# Xamarin Forms UWP - Text Color during typing

Tags: textcolor

I got an issue about the [Entry Class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Entry/) of **Xamarin Forms**. The problem is, when I'm typing a text into this `Entry`, the text is black..

The thing is, the text, before it has been tapped, is `White` and the placeholder is `Gray`, however, when I'm typing, the text is black and not `White` like I would..

There is the Entry:

```
public class CustomEntry : Entry
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The HasBorder property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty HasBorderProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(HasBorder), typeof(bool), typeof(CustomEntry), true);

    /// <summary>
    /// Assessor for the HasBorder property.
    /// </summary>
    public bool HasBorder
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(HasBorderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HasBorderProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The XAlign property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty XAlignProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("XAlign", typeof(TextAlignment), typeof(CustomEntry), TextAlignment.Start);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the X alignment of the text
    /// </summary>
    public TextAlignment XAlign
    {
        get { return (TextAlignment)GetValue(XAlignProperty); }
        set { SetValue(XAlignProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

and then, the **Renderer** for the **UWP** platform:

```
public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Instance of our Custom control declared in the PCL part.
    /// </summary>
    CustomEntry customEntry;

    /// <summary>
    /// We override the OnElementChanged() event handler to get the desired instance. We also use it for updates.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">It contains either the NewElement or the OldElement.</param>
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            customEntry = e.NewElement as CustomEntry;

            if (customEntry != null)
            {
                SetTextAlignment();
                SetBorderPresence();
                SetTextColor();
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// The on element property changed callback.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="PropertyChangedEventArgs"/>Instance containing the event data.</param>
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == CustomEntry.XAlignProperty.PropertyName)
            SetTextAlignment();
        else if (e.PropertyName == CustomEntry.HasBorderProperty.PropertyName)
            SetBorderPresence();
        else if (e.PropertyName == CustomEntry.TextColorProperty.PropertyName)
            SetTextColor();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the text alignment.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="view">The view.</param>
    private void SetTextAlignment()
    {
        switch (customEntry.XAlign)
        {
            case Xamarin.Forms.TextAlignment.Center:
                Control.TextAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.TextAlignment.Center;
                break;
            case Xamarin.Forms.TextAlignment.End:
                Control.TextAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.TextAlignment.Right;
                break;
            case Xamarin.Forms.TextAlignment.Start:
                Control.TextAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.TextAlignment.Left;
                break;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the border presence.
    /// </summary>
    private void SetBorderPresence()
    {
        if (!customEntry.HasBorder)
        {
            Control.BorderThickness = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private void SetTextColor()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("-- HEY --");
        Control.IsColorFontEnabled = true;
        Control.SelectionHighlightColor = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(126, 255, 255, 255));
        Control.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(126, 255, 255, 255));
        Control.ForegroundFocusBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(126, 255, 255, 255));
        Control.PlaceholderForegroundBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(126, 255, 255, 255));
        Control.PlaceholderForegroundFocusBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(126, 255, 255, 255));
        Control.BackgroundFocusBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(126, 255, 255, 255));
        Debug.WriteLine("-- HEY --");
    }
}
```

Does someone has any idea? I didn't try for Android/iOS..

Thank in advance for any help !

Comment: I am not a Xamarin.Forms expert, but what about changing `Element.TextColor` inside your `void SetTextColor()`?

Comment: Thank for your answer, I tried and it doesn't work too..